# No video output with GPU passthrough

Tags: linux, virtualization, arch-linux, gpu

I've been trying to get PCI/GPU passthrough to work for a few days but I've hit a wall. I can't get any video output from the passed GPU. I've followed closely the tutorial over at  Arch Wiki while occasionally checking [this one](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/play-games-in-windows-on-linux-pci-passthrough-quick-guide/108981) from Level1Techs. The OS I'm virtualizing is Windows 10 Home Edition.

PC specs:

- OS: Arch Linux with kernel version 4.10.9-1-ARCH
- CPU: Intel Core i5-6600K
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 (iGPU, used by Linux)
- GPU: AMD Radeon R9 380 (passed through)
- Mobo: Asus Z170 Pro Gaming

VT-d is enabled from the UEFI BIOS and IOMMU is enabled in the kernel (output of `dmesg | grep -i iommu`):

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=c6c3c8f3-030c-4dce-be63-8938386ac963 rw quiet intel_iommu=on
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=c6c3c8f3-030c-4dce-be63-8938386ac963 rw quiet intel_iommu=on
[    0.000000] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
...
```

My GPU and HDMI audio controller are using the `vfio-pci` driver and are in the IOMMU group 1 with a PCIe controller (output of `lspci -nnk`):

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga PRO [Radeon R9 285/380] [1002:6939] (rev f1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:2015]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 285/380] [1002:aad8]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:aad8]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`vfio-pci` is running properly, proved by `dmesg | grep -i vfio`:

```
[    0.773952] VFIO - User Level meta-driver version: 0.3
[    0.774978] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=none
[    0.789351] vfio_pci: add [1002:6939[ffff:ffff]] class 0x000000/00000000
[    0.806016] vfio_pci: add [1002:aad8[ffff:ffff]] class 0x000000/00000000
[    2.767507] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=none
[ 1310.412510] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
```

`qemu`, `libvirt`, `ovmf-git` and `virt-manager` are installed and `libvirtd` is running (output of `systemctl status libvirtd`):

```
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-04-15 12:16:01 EEST; 4h 10min ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 469 (libvirtd)
    Tasks: 21 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           ├─469 /usr/bin/libvirtd
           ├─708 /usr/bin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
           ├─709 /usr/bin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
           ├─754 /usr/bin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wireless.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
           └─755 /usr/bin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/wireless.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper

Apr 15 15:46:21 elias-arch dnsmasq[754]: using nameserver 192.168.43.1#53
Apr 15 15:46:21 elias-arch dnsmasq[708]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 15:46:21 elias-arch dnsmasq[708]: using nameserver 2001:14b8:1000::1#53
Apr 15 15:46:21 elias-arch dnsmasq[708]: using nameserver fe80::e658:b8ff:fe4a:5394%wlp4s0#53
Apr 15 15:46:21 elias-arch dnsmasq[708]: using nameserver 192.168.43.1#53
Apr 15 15:52:23 elias-arch libvirtd[469]: 2017-04-15 12:52:23.783+0000: 525: warning : qemuDomainObjTaint:4148 : Domain id=3 name='Windows10' uuid=dd4cb32a-0311-4b7c-9bd6-4553051945be is tainted: host-cpu
Apr 15 15:52:24 elias-arch libvirtd[469]: 2017-04-15 12:52:24.017+0000: 469: error : qemuMonitorIORead:588 : Unable to read from monitor: Connection reset by peer
Apr 15 15:52:24 elias-arch libvirtd[469]: 2017-04-15 12:52:24.038+0000: 469: error : qemuProcessReportLogError:1845 : internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2017-04-15T12:52:23.899918Z qemu-system-x86_64: cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram
Apr 15 15:52:24 elias-arch libvirtd[469]: 2017-04-15 12:52:24.041+0000: 525: error : qemuProcessReportLogError:1845 : internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2017-04-15T12:52:23.899918Z qemu-system-x86_64: cannot set up guest memory '
Apr 15 15:52:48 elias-arch libvirtd[469]: 2017-04-15 12:52:48.858+0000: 524: warning : qemuDomainObjTaint:4148 : Domain id=4 name='Windows10' uuid=dd4cb32a-0311-4b7c-9bd6-4553051945be is tainted: host-cpu
```

Don't worry about that `cannot set up guest memory`-error, it was a mistake of mine giving too little RAM for the VM.

My `virt-manager` settings should be alright. I'm running mostly on default settings, except:

- I'm using UEFI firmware found in `/usr/share/ovmf/x64/ovmf_x64.bin`
- CPU model is `host-passthrough`
- Two virtual storage disks: both are SCSI and using writeback cache mode
- Two virtual CDROM-disks: both are SATA, one holds the Win10 ISO and the other has the driver for SCSI drives from Red Hat.
- Extra controller for VirtIO SCSI
- USB controller is using USB 3

I installed Windows in the QXL video adapter, and it succeeded. After that, I removed the Spice channel, QXL video adapter, the emulated mouse and keyboard,  the USB tablet device and two USB redirecters. I also added two PCI Host Devices: my GPU and its HDMI audio controller. After that there was no output coming from the passed GPU (I know that the output should come to the monitor that is plugged to the dedicated video card). The system is clearly starting up: it's allocating RAM and using the processor. I've already tried this on Fedora earlier this week and failed in the same stage.

[Here's the log file from /var/log/libvirt/qemu/Windows10.log](https://pastebin.com/8xt3L4Uv)

Is there any log files I'd need to include? I'm not too familiar with KVM so I don't know. Could this be a hardware problem or am I just doing something stupid?

Thanks!

Edit: My XML config from `virsh edit Windows10`:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>Windows10</name>
  <uuid>dd4cb32a-0311-4b7c-9bd6-4553051945be</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>5120000</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>5120000</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-2.8'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/ovmf/x64/ovmf_x64.bin</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/Windows10_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'/>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/sbin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='writeback'/>
      <source file='/opt/os-storage/win10.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='writeback'/>
      <source file='/home/elias/os-images/storage/win10-data.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='scsi'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/elias/os-images/win10-amd64.iso'/>
      <target dev='sdc' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='2'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/elias/os-images/virtio-win-0.1.126.iso'/>
      <target dev='sdd' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='3'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0' model='virtio-scsi'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='nec-xhci'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:98:06:a4'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:2e:5c:88'/>
      <source network='wireless'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0b' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```